# Cut substrings between 2 characters and loop through them

Tags: arrays, bash, substring, cut

I have the following string:

```
<(name:John,sirname:Doe),(country:United States)>
```

And I want to loop through the values between parenthesis, previously removing `<` and `>`. First cycle will give `name:John,sirname:Doe`, and the second one `country:United States`. But it can have any amount of values. I don't want to use any libraries or things that don't come preinstalled in linux distros.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `gnu awk` with `FPAT` to break each field using `(...)` pattern:

```
s='<(name:John,sirname:Doe),(country:United States)>'

awk -v FPAT='\\([^)]+\\)' '{
for (h=1; h<=NF; h++) {gsub(/[()]/, "", $h); print $h}}' <<< "$s"

name:John,sirname:Doe
country:United States
```

Comment: And what if I want to change the characters? To this: `[{name:John,sirname:Doe},{country:United States}]`

Comment: Then change `FPAT` to `FPAT='\\{[^}]+\\}'`

Comment: And `gsub(/[()]/, "", $h)` to `gsub(/[{}]/, "", $h)`